# Hiding and showing elements at changing intervals

Tags: jquery

I have a headline on a website I'm programming; let's say the headline says `"LIKE THIS"`.

I'd like the word `THIS` to continually change between `THIS`  and `THAT` -- without any fading effects, but at different intervals.

Let's say I want the word THIS to be there at the beginning and stay there for 2 seconds. I then want it to change into TAHT (sic) but only for 200 milliseconds until changing into THAT and stay there for 3 seconds, until changing back to THIS, then starting the whole process over again.

I'm familiar with several `looping/cycling` plugins for `jquery (Cycle, InnerFade, etc)`, but they all seem to want to add effects -- and none of them seem to be able to provide the possibility of different intervals.

Hope to hear from someone. Thank you very much in advance.

//A.

Comment: I would create a recursive self-executing function using `setInterval` or maybe `setTimout`, it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get you started:

HTML

```
<span id="text">THIS</span>​
```

JavaScript

```
function changeToTaht() {
    // Change text, and call changeToThat, in 200ms
    $('#text').text('TAHT');
    setTimeout(changeToThat, 200);        
}   

function changeToThat() {
    // Change text, and call changeToThis, in 3000ms
    $('#text').text('THAT');
    setTimeout(changeToThis, 3000);    
}

function changeToThis() {
    // Change text, and call changeToTaht, in 3000ms
    // This will make the loop run again, and again, and again...
    $('#text').text('THIS');
    setTimeout(changeToTaht, 3000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Start the loop by calling changeToTaht, in 1000ms 
    setTimeout(changeToTaht, 1000);
});
```

​jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Webye/

Comment: I was SO close to complaining about the typo in the first function :P

Comment: :) Yes, it hurts your eyes doesn't it?

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that's spot on!
But can you please tell me what it is that makes it loop again and again (which is exactly what I wanted, I'm just not sure I understand it yet :) )

Comment: Sure, I've added comments to the code. What does the trick is that `changeToThis` waits 3000ms and calls `changeToTaht` which starts the loop over and over again. So each function invokes the next function, except for the last function that will invoke the first :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript functions of [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).  These will allow you to set off jquery functions at predefined time intervals.